# Why does my download have a "heartbeat"?

Tags: 12.04, download-speed

I sometimes download large files, and when I do I always see this kind of "heartbeat" in the speed of the download:

[image]

Although it doesn't really matter to me, I just wonder what causes this behaviour? Is it Ubuntu itself, or my router, or my ISP or maybe something else?

[edit] Just to clarify; this happens with any download, whether it be through http, ftp, or even when I'm using torrents..

Answer (score 1):

Most likely it is the source server cycling as it pre-caches the next requested segment of the file. The sample you show is actually pretty good in that the download speed remains constant and the dips aren't larger. You might see completely different results if you attempted a download from a very busy server, with bigger dips and even stalls as the server tries to cope with the I/O requests.

Comment: Are you sure that is the explanation? The thing is that I have this pattern with any download, being it through http, ftp, and also when using torrents..

Comment: If you were to look at the file transfer rates from a directly-connected local server, you'd see some equivalent of speed variations. The connection protocol isn't the issue - it's the ability of the server to read, cache, buffer, route and transmit the request for the file. Absolutely flat transfer rates just don't happen. Do other intermediary factors influence it? Sure, they do. Download a file from somewhere halfway around the world and you'll see bigger spikes and dips as the requests and data relay through the intermediary servers.

Comment: I am sure it is AN explanation. But it won't clear all your questions, specially if you are expecting to read something related to a failure in your equipment or the possibility to improve something in your system.

Comment: Ah, intermediary servers. I didn't think of that. So it is more a thing wich is caused by backbone systems (or something.. I´m way of my usual knowledge here..)?

Comment: @GeppettvsD'Constanzo - Luckily I am not after a "solution" of some kind. As said, my downspeed is more than enough for my use. It's just curiousity which ached my mind.. :)

Comment: @kramer65 Sure - run a traceroute to the server and see how many hops it has to make to get there. Every hop adds potential for a lag in the download.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility, though certainly not a sure thing, is that you're observing a [TCP congestion avoidance algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_congestion_avoidance_algorithm) in action. The sending host does not know the full capacity or latency (or current utilization) of the network between you and it ahead of time, so to maximize throughput and minimize data loss, TCP (usually the layer beneath your http, ftp, and torrents) gradually ramps up the amount of data that it sends per millisecond, until finally the connection gets clogged and the sender stops receiving all the acknowledgements it expects, at which point it backs off the rate somewhat and resumes a gradual upward climb again from that lower point. In this interpretation, those periodic "dips" would be times when the server has attempted to send more data per second than can get through and then slows down a bit.

I found a few charts of this in an image search, but they have more of a sawtooth shape rather than your heartbeat. I suppose that could be due to the difference between the perspective of the sender and the receiver, though.

Answer (score 1):

Before any conclusions can be made we need to know how this was measured. My gut tells me the heartbeat is a function of the tool you are using to measure the result. In physics they say you cannot look at something without affecting the outcome. So measurements must me made in multiple ways to be sure.

Comment: Alright, so the way this was measured was simply by looking at the System Monitor. I wouldn't know howto measure it in a different way.. Suggestions?

Comment: @kramer65 The only one I use is `nethogs` that gives me throughput of all applications, but it doesn't have graphs or does it over time.